# How to pass file to Google Drive API (MediaFileUpload) without saving it to the disk

Tags: python, google-drive-api

We have a website with React in the front-end and python in the back-end. I am trying to create a python back end (using Flask), where the user uploads a file and python uploads it to Google Drive. I have found the code for uploading a file to Google Drive via the API:

```
file_metadata = {
    'name': filename,
    'parents': [folder_id]
}
media = MediaFileUpload(uploaded_file,
                        mimetype='application/msword',
                        resumable=True)
file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                              media_body=media,
                              fields='id').execute()
```

This code work where uploaded_file is a path on the disk. However, I would like to upload the file to Google without having to save it to the disk first (as it would take up space and we would have to delete it afterwards). I have tried passing the file directly as I get it from the Flask request object.

```
uploaded_file = request.files['file']
```

Then I get the message "expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not FileStorage". I tried

```
uploaded_file = request.files['file'].read()
```

to get the file in bytes. Then I get the message "'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: invalid continuation byte". From what I read this means the encoding is not 'utf-8' but something else, but we can't know beforehand what encoding the files the users will upload will have, and I can't find a way to find it. Any suggestions, apart from saving the file to the disk and explicitly deleting it after it's uploaded to Google drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cat use `MediaIoBaseUpload` from `googleapiclient.http`

```
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseUpload
import io


f = io.BytesIO(b'mybytestring')
MediaIoBaseUpload(f, mimetype='application/msword')
```

Comment: MediaIoBaseUpload worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `io` buffer to save the uploaded file , without needing to write it to disk. See an example below.

```
import io
uploaded_file: FileStorage = request.files['file']
buffer = io.BytesIO()
buffer.name = uploaded_file.filename
uploaded_file.save(buffer)
media = MediaFileUpload(buffer,
                        mimetype='application/msword',
                        resumable=True)
```

Comment: This didn't work because MediaFileUpload doesn't accept io.BytesIO. Used MediaIoBaseUpload as suggested below, and that worked.